# Getting Total Value from a Loop

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem solving a code; I'm trying to get a total value from every loop but every time the loop happens, it instead overwrite the previous value with the new one.

**Different Explanation:**
I need the loop to keep adding value to the previous pow so if I input 3 for atk, it should add `1st Loop [50(Base)+50] + 2nd Loop [50(Base)+50+50], 3rd Loop [50(Base)+50+50+50]` and then I want the loop to total all of those value which is `450` in the end. Hope I explained it right.```

I'm very new to C++ and I hope you could teach me how to do it.

I've tried using for, do while, and if.

```
//variables
int base=50; //base damage
int up=50;  //damage increase per hit
int atk=0;  //number of attacks
int pow=0;  //total attack power

scanf("%d", &atk); //input number of attacks

while (atk >= 1) //number of attacks loop
{
    pow += atk * up + base;  //total attack power calculation
    atk--; //every time attack happens, subtract 1 from remaining attacks
}
printf("%d\n", pow); //total attack power
```

I expect the compiled code to look like this.
I copy pasted this example output from my homework problem.

```
Explanation
For Sample Test Case 3, damage for every hit by Templor Assasson :
• Hit 1 : 100 + 0 = 100
• Hit 2 : 100 + 50 = 150
• Hit 3 : 100 + 100 = 200
Thus, total damage of Templor Assasson is 450.
```

[PROBLEM SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg9zS.png)

Comment: I think you want `pow = pow + (atk * base);` am I right?

Comment: First of all, remember that uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random or garbage) value. Secondly, perhaps you want to *add* to `pow`?

Comment: I guess you need to do pow += atk * base;

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments, but ```pow = pow + (atk * base)``` that's not quite what I'm looking for, I've edited the post and added image link to make my intention clearer.

I didn't put any value to atk and pow because it is not predetermined and will depend on the inputted value when the code is compiled, is that a bad thing to do?

Thanks

Comment: With what you have now, you compute the value of `pow` `atk` times, but only the last value survives the loop.

Comment: Yes that is what happen with the current code, but I need the loop to keep adding value to the previous pow so if I input 3 for atk, it should add ```1st Loop [50(Base)+50] + 2nd Loop [50(Base)+50+50], 3rd Loop [50(Base)+50+50+50]``` and then I want the loop to total all of those value in the end. Hope I explained it right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are missing the 100 * base (initial number of attack, e,g - 3).
2. uninitialized pow, use `int pow = 0;`
3. you should add up (atk * up). Just as mentioned in the comment, e.g - `pow += atk * up;`
4. You are adding `(n * up) + (n-1 * up) + .... + (1 * up)` look at the example carefully specially the value of `n`. Hint - compare the first round value of (n * base) of yours with example.
5. Once you solve it a bonus trivia for you. You can do it in one line, without any loop

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I didn't quite understand number 1 and 4 but I have tried fixing the code and edited it on my post. Hope you can help me again.

Comment: this is wrong ```pow += atk * up + up;``` did you mean ```pow += base + atk * up;``` ?

Comment: @WOTA looking at the example you gave, how many times you need to add up the base? that was the 1. Think about atk = 2, then atk = 3 and atk = 4. By then you should see a pattern.

Comment: 4. is look at the example again, what is the lowest value of atk your loop count? what is the example given? You should see your main problem then

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have read your tips and fixed the code once again and it worked! But I still want to try the one lined version you said on number 5. If it is fine, would you tell me some tips of how to write it? Thank you

Comment: @WOTA wc & np. Take ```base```. how many times you need to add up base? does it have any correlation with atk? Same thing with ```up```. Once you can you can covert it to an equation.